# check last id data with current id data in php to avoid duplication in database

Tags: php

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['gender']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone_number'])) 
{
    try {
        $stmtt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' email = '".($_POST['email'])."'phone_number='".$_POST['phone_number']."'");
        $stmtt->execute();
        if($stmt1->fetchColumn()!=1) {
            die("cannot continue");
        } else {
            $fl = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password,name,gender,email,phone) VALUES('".$_POST['username']."','".md5($_POST['password'])."','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['gender']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['phone_number']."')");
             $fl->execute();
        }
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "fields ".$ex->getMessage();   
    }
}
```

Comment: after form submit again and again data is being duplicated

Comment: after removing the code {
        $stmtt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' email = '".($_POST['email'])."'phone_number='".$_POST['phone_number']."'");
        $stmtt->execute();
        if($stmt1->fetchColumn()!=1) {
            die("cannot continue");
        } else {

Comment: it worked but data is duplicated wen form is submitted again

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your code:

```
$stmtt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) 
                         FROM users 
                         WHERE username = :username
                           AND email = :email
                           AND phone_number = :phoneNumber");
        $stmtt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
        $stmtt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
        $stmtt->bindParam(':phoneNumber', $_POST['phone_number'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
        $stmtt->execute();
        if($stmtt->rowCount() != 1) {
```

You must use binds in order to prevent sql injections...

Comment: i need to know how to check the last id data in database with the current entered data in the form

Comment: query for last id and check the data of that id with the current data